# apply jquery attribute to another div

Tags: jquery, dynamic, attributes, slider

I am using a jquery slider which automatically generates pagination bullets with the following html output:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="current"><a href="#0">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can see an example of this at http://pixelcakecreative.com/

I want to be able to reset the slides position (set it back to the first slide) when you click on one of the following anchor links:

```
<li><a href="#" rel="#panel-1" class="activeSlide pita">Trendz<div class="buttonFade"></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pita" rel="#panel-2">Decibel<div class="buttonFade"></div></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="pita" rel="#panel-3">UCC<div class="buttonFade"></div></a></li>
```

The slider is actually 3 sliders within a div that switches it's position based on whatever anchor (above code) is clicked. So basically, when you click on any of the links that switch the project slider, I want to go back to the first image of the slider.

I tried this with no luck, any idea on how to do this?

Ill start off the jquery with my existing code for clicking one of the trigger links:

```
$('#pixel-slider ul a.pita').click(function () {

     $('#pixel-slider ul a').removeClass('activeSlide');
     $(this).addClass('activeSlide');   
     $('.maskss').scrollTo($(this).attr('rel'), 500);

//solution below
```

$('.pagination li:nth-child(1) a').click();

```
return false;       
});
```

UPDATE: I Found solution:  $('.pagination li:nth-child(1) a').click();

Comment: Could you provide a little more explanation of the context to aid in understanding the situation?

Comment: Is this two questions or one? " I want to be able to reset the slides position (set it back to the first slide) from an outside anchor link" and " I want to use jquery to take the href attribute from the FIRST anchor link, and apply it to a div with an id of #click". Try to numerate the things you want to happen, and what triggers them.

Comment: Yeah, need more info, I'm trying to visualize this, your explanation isn't the best. Try refining your question a bit

Comment: ok i reworded the question and provided an example on the homepage of my upcoming site

Comment: solution found:  $('.pagination li:nth-child(1) a').click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution will work but you can simply use the `first` selector instead of using `nth-child` and passing 1. `li:first` will select the first element under `.pagination` element.

```
 $('.pagination li:first a').click();
```